# Recursive function in useImperativeHandle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My code is like below but I getting checkSome is not defined error, from inside the checkSome function, how can I call checkSome(el)

```
useImperativeHandle (ref, ()=> ({ 
    checkSome(prop) {
      userIds.push(prop.id);
      if (prop.children == null) return;
      prop.children.forEach((el) => {
        checkSome(el);
      });
  }}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` keyword. Try this:

```
useImperativeHandle (ref, ()=> ({ 
    checkSome(prop) {
      userIds.push(prop.id);
      if (prop.children == null) return;
      prop.children.forEach((el) => {
        this.checkSome(el);
      });
  }}));
```

You can read more from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp).